# How can i renew an expired or create self-signed certificate key any.pem Poco c++ using openssl

Tags: c++, ssl, poco-libraries

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE ... 1Ozy
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,0950752701CB74AF

OmaLd ... hWh8GKd
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Answer (score 1):

I answered my questions

Openssl> req -x509 -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout any.pem -out any.pem

(pass phrase = secret)

Openssl> req -new -key -any.pem -out server.csr

Openssl> x509 -req -in server.csr -signkey any.pem -out rootcert.pem

Answer (score 0):

Small update and how to run

Because of error: `140006379889088:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:74:fopen('-any.pem','r')`

```
openssl req -x509 -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout any.pem -out any.pem
openssl req -new -key any.pem -out server.csr #no more -any.pem
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -signkey any.pem -out rootcert.pem
```